# flutter plugin cloud_firestore could not be built because CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations [flutter build apk]

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a flutter app that uses several firebase dependencies but the cloud_firestore dependency always returns errors when debugging and building the app.
**Here is the Build Log**

```
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                
Note: /flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cloud_firestore-0.13.4+2/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/firebase/cloudfirestore/CloudFirestorePlugin.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                                                                 
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.                                                         
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.                                                                 
Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/323813f5a095cba9aa563dadb749a1cb/android.jar with input /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-28/android.jar
Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/ff23381473fa92d0c047c8663bfbe6a6/android.jar with input /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-27/android.jar
Calling mockable JAR artifact transform to create file: /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/43c9f60e6803ddaaef16828845e40f49/android.jar with input /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-29/android.jar
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 329KB to 261KB: Removed 20%                            

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                                                           

* What went wrong:                                                                                                 
Execution failed for task ':google_sign_in:verifyReleaseResources'.                                                
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade                  
   > Android resource linking failed                                                                               
     /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/9dacf9516413cf5e5b34c6b4508340e4/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

     /Users/user/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/9dacf9516413cf5e5b34c6b4508340e4/core-1.0.0/res/values/values.xml:57:5-88:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.


* Try:                                                                                                             
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                                                                         

BUILD FAILED in 7m 10s                                                                                             
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                                                                           
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     441.0s (!)
The built failed likely due to AndroidX incompatibilities in a plugin. The tool is about to try using Jetfier to solve the incompatibility.
✏️  Creating 'android/settings_aar.gradle'...                       35ms
✓ 'android/settings_aar.gradle' created successfully.
Building plugin cloud_firestore...
The plugin cloud_firestore could not be built due to the issue above.
```

**pubspec.yaml firebase dependencies used:**

```
firebase_core: ^0.4.4+3
cloud_firestore: ^0.13.4+2
firebase_auth: ^0.15.5+2
```

Anyone with working firebase dependencies kindly share them below.

Comment: Seems that is a knowed behavior:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110797725

How I can reproduce this?

Comment: @Mario I do not know how to reproduce it, I just used the latest versions of firebase dependencies that's when I encountered it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that is a transient issue and some piece of the tools stack is not synchronized correctly.

My suggestion is to reload the dependencies and the tools involved since in the [Issue Tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/110797725) things like Android Studio, or Gradle are restored by:

1. Removing folders: /.gradle and /.gradle
2. Trying to setup using local gradle distribution.

Hope this was useful!

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem, try two things:

1. In project/android/app/build.gradle

   ```
   defaultConfig {
     ...
      multiDexEnabled true
   }
   ```
2. In terminal run `flutter pub upgrade`

Comment: `MultiDexEnabled` is set to `true` then run `flutter clean`  then `flutter pub upgrade` yet I got the same error